# Wordpress/Timber/ACF create slide for each image

Tags: wordpress, twig, advanced-custom-fields, timber

I use Timber for Wordpress and ACF.

I would like to create a structure like that :

```
<div class="section" id="section1">
      <div class="slide slide0">
              <div class="image-container" data-type="home" data-currentslide="1" data-maxslides="3"  data-title="DEMO" data-project="Sweater Collection (Hamburg, 2017)">
                  <img src="img/myimage.jpg">
              </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide slide1">
              <div class="image-container" data-type="project" data-currentslide="2" data-maxslides="3"  data-title="DEMO" data-project="Sweater Collection (Hamburg, 2017)">
                  <img src="img/myimage.jpg">
              </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide slide2">
              <div class="image-container" data-type="project" data-currentslide="3" data-maxslides="3"  data-title="DEMO" data-project="Sweater Collection (Hamburg, 2017)">
                  <img src="img/myimage.jpg">
              </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section" id="section2">
      <div class="slide slide0">
              <div class="image-container" data-type="project" data-currentslide="1" data-maxslides="3"  data-title="DEMO" data-project="Sweater Collection (Hamburg, 2017)">
                  <img src="img/myimage.jpg">
              </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide slide1">
              <div class="image-container" data-type="project" data-currentslide="2" data-maxslides="3"  data-title="DEMO" data-project="Sweater Collection (Hamburg, 2017)">
                  <img src="img/myimage.jpg">
              </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide slide2">
              <div class="image-container" data-type="project" data-currentslide="3" data-maxslides="3"  data-title="DEMO" data-project="Sweater Collection (Hamburg, 2017)">
                  <img src="img/myimage.jpg">
              </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

I created a Custom Post Type called "projets". And I want to create a div for each "projets" post.

```
$context = Timber::get_context();
$context['projets'] = Timber::get_posts(array('post_type' => 'projets', 'posts_per_page' => '-1'));
```

This loop work fine

```
{% for projet in projets %}
        <div class="section" id="section{{loop.index}}">

        </div>
{% endfor %}
```

In each post I created a repeater field for images (called "project_imgs"). Each image must create a slide. But I didn't manage to create this second loop. Can I have some help to create my second loop please ?

[image: My ACF Structure]

```
{% for slide in slides.get_field('project_imgs') %}
            <div class="slide slide{{ loop.index0 }}">
               <div class="image-container" data-type="home" data-currentslide="1" data-maxslides="1" data-title="Title" data-project="+49(0)1520 8819162 Berlin&amp;Hamburg (GERMANY)">
                  <img src="img/myimage.jpg">
              </div> 
            </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The other problem is to increment `data-currentslide="1" data-maxslides="1"`

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Junaid's answer, the code would be potentially better structured like this:

```
{% set projectImgs = slides.get_field('project_imgs') %}

{% for slide in projectImgs %}
  <div class="slide slide{{ loop.index }}">
     <div class="image-container" data-type="home" data-currentslide="{{ loop.index }}" data-maxslides="{{ projectImgs | length }}" data-title="Title" data-project="+49(0)1520 8819162 Berlin&amp;Hamburg (GERMANY)">
        <img src="{{ slide.project_img_desktop }}" 
             srcset="{{ slide.project_img_mobile }} 360w,
                     {{ slide.project_img_desktop }} 2000w" />
    </div> 
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Apologies if this doesn't clear anything up - just thought I would put srcset out there for use for your different image sizes. Also using the loop index more rather than a count would make sense as this increments anyway.

Comment: {{ loop.index }} worked for me with ACF repeater. Also for the flexible content inside acf repeater.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (not tested)

```
{% set count = 1 %}
{% for slide in slides.get_field('project_imgs') %}
  <div class="slide slide{{ loop.index0 }}">
     <div class="image-container" data-type="home" data-currentslide="{{count}}" data-maxslides="{{count}}" data-title="Title" data-project="+49(0)1520 8819162 Berlin&amp;Hamburg (GERMANY)">
        <img src="img/myimage.jpg">
    </div> 
  </div>
{% set count = count + 1 %}
{% endfor %}
```

Just a thought, should the `maxslides` represent the maximum number of slides available? If so, then use the following code instead.

```
{% set count = 1 %}
{% for slide in slides.get_field('project_imgs') %}
  <div class="slide slide{{ loop.index0 }}">
     <div class="image-container" data-type="home" data-currentslide="{{count}}" data-maxslides="{{ slides.get_field('project_imgs')|length }}" data-title="Title" data-project="+49(0)1520 8819162 Berlin&amp;Hamburg (GERMANY)">
        <img src="img/myimage.jpg">
    </div> 
  </div>
{% set count = count + 1 %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes maxslides represent the maximum number of images in each project. Unfortunately that don't work. I have a repeater field called project_imgs in wich I have two image fields called project_img_desktop and project_img_mobile, I'm lost

Comment: I update my question with a screenshot, to show my acf structure

Comment: @xroad I don't know how you're planning to use the images for desktop and mobile but to use the desktop image for the slide replace `<img src="img/myimage.jpg">` with `<img src="{{slide.project_img_desktop}}">`